# Mobile GPU accelerated slideToggle functionality

Tags: jquery, ios, css, mobile, hardware-acceleration

I'm developing an interface for a mobile app in HTML and CSS. The app uses a lot of forms and I want to use jQuery slideToggle functionality to show and hide the less frequently used elements.

jQuery animations run very poorly on mobile devices, so after some research it seems that only transform: translate3d() in CSS will invoke hardware acceleration on webkit mobile browsers.

Any thoughts on how I can create a slide toggle using CSS translate 3d?

Thanks guys,

G

Comment: This is an interesting topic, but I think you're going to get better answers with a more specific question.

Comment: Hi G, could you add some sample code as well, and a little bit more description so we can understand what exactly your are trying to do?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the replies. I've ended up solving it in a different way.
What I was trying to do was replicate the jQuery slideToggle function, where content can be hidden and slide up and down on touch. Very easy to do but the performance is terrible on mobile devices as it's handled by the CPU. 

Some CSS properties are hardware accelerated on mobile webkit browsers, mainly translate3D, using this property results in very smooth animation. 

In the end I had to hide the content by placing an element on top of it, then slide it downing using translateY().

Answer (score 1):

Using tranlateY() is still not using hardware acceleration.

If you still want to use jQuery Mobile for the toggle effect, you should make changes to the Jquery Mobile CSS.

Look for this:

```
.slide.in {
            -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
            -webkit-animation-name: slideinfromright;
            }
.slide.out {
            -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
            -webkit-animation-name: slideouttoleft;
        }

@-webkit-keyframes slideinfromright {
            from { -webkit-transform: translateX(100%); }
            to { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
        }
@-webkit-keyframes slideouttoleft {
            from { -webkit-transform: translateX(0); }
            to { -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%); }
        }
```

(see here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0-rc.1/docs/pages/page-customtransitions.html)
And change:

```
"translateX(-100%)" to "translate3d(-100%,0,0)"<br>
"translateX(0)" to "translate3d(0,0,0)"<br>
"translateX(100%)" to "translate3d(100%,0,0)"
```

This will make jQuery for mobile transition smoother for webkit devices.

From Webkit:

> translate3d(x, y, z) Move the element in x, y and z,
>   and just move the element in z. Positive z is towards the viewer.
>   Unlike x and y, the z value cannot be a percentage.
>   https://www.webkit.org/blog/386/3d-transforms/

It's known that the use of translate3d pushes CSS animations into hardware acceleration. Even if you're looking to do a basic 2d translation, use translate3d for more power!

http://davidwalsh.name/translate3d

This way you can achieve what you're looking for.

Diego Trigo

Comment: Many thanks diego! 
However, I'm not using jQuery mobile, just straight up HTML, CSS and some jquery. 
Though I can still apply your technique! Thanks again!

Comment: Yep, you can still apply it to normal jQuery... Just create your own animation using CSS, and then trigger it by jQuery (like adding the class with the animation properties)

Answer (score 0):

Just want to let you know that version 1.3.1 of JQuery mobile is using translate3d for its slide animation. 1.3.0 did not.